# Как подключить entity к базе данных?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Установил Sql сервер на удаленной машине. Хочу добавить entity модель в проект, выбираю from database, нажимаю создать новое подключение, выбираю провайдер и открывается окно в котором нужно ввести имя сервера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все туториалы которые я нашел, подключались к локальному sql, что туда писать, чтоб подключить сервер на удаленной машине?

Comment: Попробуйте вписать в поле Server Name имя сервера :)

Comment: @PashaPash, как это должно было помочь? Он выдает ошибку, что не находит такого сервера, потому что на локальной машине его нет.

Comment: Вы, наверное, как-то не так сообщение об ошибке трактуете. Приведите его в вопросе, вместе с вписанным вами именем сервера.

Comment: @PashaPash, вот Вам скриншот ошибки с именем сервера который, повторю, на удаленной машине! http://i.imgur.com/XTRnpcT.png

Comment: Указывается `адрес\название` инстанса, а не только название.

Comment: @Monk, что служит адресом? просто ip\sqlexpress?

Comment: по моему достаточно, попробуйте

Comment: @Monk, та же ошибка. Не хватает чего-то.

Comment: @anweledig указывать надо имясервера\имяинстанса. Если на сервере myserver установлен sqlexpress - то указывать надо myserver\sqlexpress. Иначе как EF догадается, к какому серверу ему подключаться. Кроме того, sql express по умолчанию не разрешает подключения с других машин, его надо настраивать - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012. Попробуйте для начала правильно вписать имя, если не пустит - проверяйте настройки SQL (как по ссылке) и заодно настройки firewall на сервере (просто отключите его на время)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была прозаичней, чем я думал. При создании sql инстанса, нужно было указать пароль, при этом стоял стандартный логин `sa`, который я не успел увидеть подтвердив настройки. Дальше я создавал других пользователей, но почему-то зайти смог только с логином `sa` и паролем который я указал в самом начале.